# Rich snippets appear in Google search results for pages without structured data

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

I was wondering if there's a way to get Google to display rich text results without implementing any kind of structured data.

When Google displays a link to a page, it may also display some extra information under the link. This is what Google refers to as "rich snippets" or "rich results". So, for a product page, it could list things like warranty information, rating, price, brand, etc.

I came across a search result for a website that displays some of that extra information, but when I scanned  it using Google's [Rich Results Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), it didn't seem to have any kind of structured data, and it says

> This page is not eligible for rich results.

This is rather puzzling. What am I missing? Is there another way to indicate to the Google crawler which information to use? Do I absolutely have to implement Google's structured data in order for these extra bits of information to appear?

Example:
As can be seen in the image below, it lists rating, reviews, price range and "In Stock"

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the type of result?  I suspect that it is a "knowledge graph" result.

Comment: Added a screenshot in the main post. As you can see, it shows rating, number of reviews, price and in stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article "[Google: structured data not required for rich snippets but recommended](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-structured-data-rich-snippets-24705.html)" published on *Search Engine Roundtable* on Nov 1, 2017, one can read:

> Google's John Mueller confirmed on Twitter that technically, you do not need structured data for Google to apply rich snippets in the search results to your site. John added that although it is not needed, it would be rare to see a search result with rich snippets that does not also use structured data. So obviously it is recommended that you use structured data on your site so that you can help ensure you get rich snippets in the Google search results.

I imagine that Google algorithms identify keywords and frequently used patterns to extract relevant data and use them in rich snippets.